# hostapd is adding a route and default gw on wlan interface

Tags: networking, wireless, hostapd

I'm having a race condition where I'm starting hostapd *before* I'm able to set up my internet connection (through a GSM USB dongle). If this happens, hostapd is adding a route and default GW to the configuration of the host that is killing my network configuration:

Without starting hostapd:

`$ sudo ip route show
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.116 metric 202`

After starting hostapd:

`$ sudo ip route show
default dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.62.234 metric 303 
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.116 metric 202 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.62.234 metric 303`

hostapd config file:

`interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
channel=7
ssid=foo
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=bar
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP`

How can I ask hostapd to *not* mess up with my IP addresses and routing configuration?

Comment: There is something a little bit unclear for me. Can you please explain where you want the traffic to go by default? I guess it should go through the GSM dongle. Can you give the output from `ip route show` when the GSM connection is established but without *hostapd*? Im using *systemd-networkd*. Is this an option for you? Then you can configure dependencies and routes.

Comment: If no hostapd is running then you get the route set on ppp0 and the default gateway using ppp0 and I get to surf normally _but_ you are throwing more variables into the mix. I already did the experiments to figure out why routing was breaking and ended up pointing the blame on hostapd. I was already able to make ppp force the default gateway by adding this option into /etc/ppp/options: `defaultroute`. This way ppp overwrote the default gateway that had been set by hostapd... but I'd like to avoid having hospapd settting the default gw in the first place.